# Многопоточная программа работает медленнее

Tags: c++, алгоритм, многопоточность

Начинаю пробовать писать многопоточные программы. В качестве упражнения написал программу, которая многопоточно множит матрицы. Однако почему-то с любым кол-вом потоков она работает медленнее чем однопоточная. Вот исходник моей программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <ctime>

typedef int ElementT;
int freeLineIndex = 0;
std::mutex mtx;
void multLines(const ElementT *const*s1, const ElementT *const*s2, ElementT **d, size_t lineSize)
{
    while(true)
    {
        mtx.lock();
        size_t curLineIndex = freeLineIndex++;
        mtx.unlock();
        if (curLineIndex >= lineSize) {
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < lineSize; ++i) {
            ElementT tmpSum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < lineSize; ++j) {
                tmpSum += s1[curLineIndex][j]*s2[j][i];
            }
            d[curLineIndex][i] = tmpSum;
        }

    }
}
ElementT ** randMatrix(size_t size)
{
    ElementT **m = (ElementT**)calloc(size,sizeof(ElementT*));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        m[i] = (ElementT*)calloc(size,sizeof(ElementT));
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
            m[i][j] = (rand()%199)-99;
        }
    }
    return m;
}
int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    size_t matrixSize;
    std::cout<<"Input matrix size: "; std::cin>>matrixSize;
    ElementT **m1 = randMatrix(matrixSize);
    ElementT **m2 = randMatrix(matrixSize);
    ElementT **d = randMatrix(matrixSize);
    char c;
    std::cout<<"Use multi-threading(y or n)? ";std::cin>>c;
    clock_t t;
    if(c == 'y')
    {
        std::cout<<"Multi-threading..."<<std::endl;
        int countThreads;
        std::cout<<"Input count threads: ";std::cin>>countThreads;
        std::thread** pool = (std::thread**)calloc(countThreads,sizeof(std::thread*));
        t = clock();
        for (int i = 0; i < countThreads; ++i) {
            pool[i] = new std::thread(multLines,m1,m2,d,matrixSize);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < countThreads; ++j) {
            (*pool[j]).join();
            delete pool[j];
        }
        t = clock()-t;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"Classic method..."<<std::endl;
        t = clock();
        multLines(m1,m2,d,matrixSize);
        t = clock()-t;
    }
    std::cout<<"time: "<<t<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Я пробовал тестировать и на больших размерах матриц(1000*1000) но результат тот же. В чем тут может быть проблема?
Компилирую вот так:

```
g++ -pthread -std=c++17 -O3 main.cpp -o res
```

Comment: Думаю, у вас очень большие накладные расходы на блокировки. Попробуйте переписать алгоритм так, чтобы каждый поток при создании/вызове получал информацию о той части работы, которую ему нужно выполнить.

Comment: Вполне вероятно, что расходы на создание потоков и синхронизацию больше, чем выигрыш, который вы получаете от распараллеливания. Попробуйте увеличить размер матриц ещё для тестов.

Comment: @VladD там все равно на каждую строку лок идет. Нужно увеличивать размер порции, обрабатываемой каждым тредом. И лучше вообще избегать блокировки, IMHO

Comment: Реально - сколько потоков вы создаете?

Comment: @Harry Разное кол-во пробовал: от 4 до 1000. Все равно работает медленнее.

Comment: Ну, при 1000 не удивительно. Вообще говоря, *вычислительных* (не ждущих) потоков не следует создавать больше, чем количество ядер.

Comment: Запусти тут http://rextester.com/live/KVNE53369, многопоточный вариант быстрее работает

Comment: непонятно зачем что-то синхронизировать тут с помощью мютексов , умножение матриц очень легко параллелизируется безо всякой сихронизации - каждый элемент результирующей матрицы получается не зависимо от всех остальных, что означает что потоки мешать друг другу не будут

Comment: @ampawd если не синхронизировать, то потоки могут дублировать работу друг друга.

Comment: @Asem это вы вобще говорите или на примере вашего алгоритма ?

Comment: @ampawd на примере моего,  конечно